Tautological line bundle $L = L_{\mathbb{CP}^n}$ over $\mathbb{CP}^n$ has first Chern class $c_1(L) \neq 0$
Show that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the tautological line bundle $L = L_{\mathbb{CP}^n}$ over $\mathbb{CP}^n$ has first Chern class $c_1(L) \neq 0$.

My try:
Since $L$ is of (complex) rank one, a local frame over an open $U \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ is just a nowhere vanishing local section of $L$ defined over $U$. We choose here $U$ to be
$U_0 := \{[z_0 : z_1 : \dots : z_n] : z_0 \neq 0\},$
i.e., the domain of the standard chart
$\chi_0 : U_0 \to \mathbb{C}^n, \quad [1 : z_1 : \dots : z_n] \leftrightarrow (z_1, \dots, z_n).$
Over $U_0$, we have the local section $e_0$ given by that sends $[1 : z_1 : \dots : z_n]$ to $(1, z_1, \dots, z_n)$.
I computed the connection matrix of $\nabla$ w.r.t. a local frame $e$, which will be a $\mathbb{C}$-valued 1-form on $U$, denoted $\omega \in \Omega^1(U_0, \mathbb{C}).$ :
as the pull-back via $\chi_0$ of
$\frac{\bar{z}_1 dz_1 + \dots + \bar{z}_n dz_n}{1 + |z_1|^2 + \dots + |z_n|^2} \in \Omega^1(\mathbb{C}^n, \mathbb{C}),$
where$z_k = x_k + i y_k$ stand for the coordinate functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$, $z_k = x_k - i y_k$, $dz_k = dx_k + i \, dy_k$ (a $\mathbb{C}$-valued 1-form).
Interpreting $e_0$ as a local frame we can now talk about the curvature matrix of $\nabla$ w.r.t. $e_0$, which is now a $\mathbb{C}$-valued 2-form on $U_0$, denoted $k \in \Omega^2(U_0, \mathbb{C}).$
I tried computing $k$ but it is a mess. I just managed to computed for the case $n=1$ as (the pull-back via $\chi_0$ of) $-\frac{1}{(1 + |z|^2)^2} \, dz \wedge d\bar{z} \in \Omega^2(\mathbb{C}^n, \mathbb{C}).$
How would you compute it for the n case and show that $c_1(L) \neq 0$? Is there maybe a better approach that avoids that calculation?
Edit: Attempt of a solution following the suggestion in the comments:
Defining the Inclusion Map and pulling back the Tautological Line Bundle $L$ to $\mathbb{CP}^1$:
$$
  i: \mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^n, \quad [z_0 : z_1] \mapsto [z_0 : z_1 : 0 : \dots : 0]
  $$
The pullback $i^*L$ is a line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^1$.For each point $p \in \mathbb{CP}^1$, the fiber $(i^*L)_p$ is $L_{i(p)}$.
The fiber $L_{i(p)}$ over $i(p)$ in $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is the line $\{ \lambda \cdot i(p) \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \}$.Since $i$ maps $p$ to $[z_0 : z_1 : 0 : \dots : 0]$, the line $L_{i(p)}$ corresponds to $\{ \lambda (z_0, z_1, 0, \dots, 0) \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \}$. In conclusion the pullback bundle $i^*L$ is precisely the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^1$: $ i^*L = L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$
Using naturality of Chern classes $c_1(i^*L) = i^*c_1(L)$
Since $i^*L = L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$, we have:$c_1(L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}) = i^*c_1(L)$
I had shown before that $c_1(L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}) \neq 0 \quad \text{in} \quad H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb{Z})$
I have the Cohomology Groups:

$H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.
$H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 1$.

and the pullback map induced by $i$:
$$
  i^*: H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1; \mathbb{Z})
  $$
Since $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1; \mathbb{Z})$ and $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n; \mathbb{Z})$ are both isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, the pullback map $i^*$ can be represented by multiplication by an integer.
The inclusion $i$ maps $\mathbb{CP}^1$ into $\mathbb{CP}^n$ in such a way that the generator of $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n; \mathbb{Z})$ pulls back to the generator of $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1; \mathbb{Z})$.
Therefore, the Pullback Map $i^*$ Is Nonzero and Injective on $H^2$: Since $i^*c_1(L) = c_1(L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}) \neq 0$, it follows that $c_1(L) \neq 0$ in $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n; \mathbb{Z})$.
Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, That $c_1(L) = 0$ in $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n; \mathbb{Z})$.Then its pullback would be zero: $i*c_1(L) = i^*(0) = 0$
But we have established that:$ i^*c_1(L) = c_1(L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}) \neq 0$ This contradiction shows that $c_1(L)$ must be nonzero.

If the form is exact on $\Bbb CP^1$, what is its integral?

@It is 0. I know how it is done for n=1, my problem is the general case

Use naturality (consider the inclusion of $\Bbb CP^1$ into $\Bbb CP^n$ and the cohomology structure).

@TedShifrin Could you elaborate? I don't know what to do with that

Pull back the tautological bundle of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ to $\mathbb{C}P^1$, and observe that its going to be the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^1$. You showed that the pull back of the Chern class is non trivial. This is the $n=1$ case. So, by the proporties of cohomology you know that the chern class is non trivial either.

@Elad  Could you check if my solution is correct?. also I am using that the cohomology groups are $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1; \mathbb{Z}) $ Can this be rewriten without the $\mathbb{Z}$ part? I only saw in the lecture that $c_1(E)$was an element of $H^2(M, \mathbb{R})$ instead of of $H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})$.

@Elad What properties of cohomology did you had in mind for your suggestion?

Your solution now looks fine to me.

@red_trumpet I am using these facts that I am not familiar with $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.
and $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^n; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 1$., any way to prove them or is it too involved? and also how do I justify that the cohomology groups are $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1; \mathbb{Z}) $ rather than just $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^1; \mathbb{R}) $?
